# Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography DLL's in GAC

Tags: c#, dll, gac, sqlgeography

I installed the Nuget `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` and have a version of DLL issue.
I have read the readme and added the line in the global.asax (Webform web app)

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));
}
```

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: [A]Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography kan niet worden geconverteerd naar [B]Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography. Type A is afkomstig uit Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91 in de context Default op locatie C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types\10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll. Type B is afkomstig uit Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91 in de context Default op locatie C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll.

It failed on this line:

```
var bla = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new
{
    Loc = x.Field<Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography>("theLocation") // breaks
}).ToList();
```

theLocation is of datatype geography in my Sql Server 2008, so no 2016 `FOR JSON PATH` option for me unfortunatly.

ps. some background info: I installed nuget GeoJSON.Net and GeoJSON.Net.Contrib.MsSqlSpatial to get the geography datatype rows as geojson. Or should I just add .tostring in my sql and parse it as geojson point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found here from [Arne Klein (8 May 2014 5:08 AM)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/12/09/microsoft-sqlserver-types-nuget-package-spatial-on-azure.aspx#10523696)

> The SqlClient loads by default the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types Version 10.0 and with SQL Server 2012 V. 11 is needed. This problem can be solved by adding the following to the web.config.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

> It would be great if the Nuget package could be updated to automatically add this to the web.config.

I agree with Arne, that addition would be great.

Comment: In my case that was `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />`